# Using Devise and has_many/belongs_to to associate user with many of something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a `Animal` model and a `User` model.  A `User` can have many `Animals`.  I'm using the [Devise Gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise) for my users.  Currently I have no associations between users and animals but I want to let users have `0` or more animals.

This is what I have added so far:

`app/models/animal.rb`:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user # not sure if this is needed
   attr_accessible :name, :age
end
```

`app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :animal
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Do I need to write a migration?  Is there anything else I need to add?  Is the above correct?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). All the answers to your question are there. Learn it, there is no way around it. Good luck

Comment: Solved problem thanks to http://azimuthonline.com/blog/rails-active-record-many-to-many-relationship-using-habtm

Answer (score 3):

You need to pluralize the has many side of the relationship

```
has_many :animals
```

You need migrations to create the tables for these two models, the database doesn't know anything about your models. This is pretty basic stuff though, you may want to go through some rails tutorials first. You can use scaffolds/generators for the migrations or write them manually.